# How do i input a string with conditional input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am solving a program that allows input of a string which should contain only following characters: `'a','b' and 'c'`

Any other letter or number if entered should be rejected as soon as user enters the string and press enter.

How should I do that?

Comment: It's called *characters* (or letters). Not "alphabets".

Answer (score 2):

This is how such a program would work, as a general outline:

1. First you ask for input.
2. Then you check is there is anything else that 'a', 'b' or 'c' in the input.
3. If there is, you reject the input.

Try that, and come back, with a new question, once you have a real question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
name = input("input string: ")
if not re.search(r'[^abc]', name):
    # valid string, do what you need
    pass
```

Of course, if you expect several inputs the above code should go inside a loop, but that's an entirely different question.

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe:

```
for char in string:
    if char > "c":
        (reject it)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `input` function. I think you want to ask this function name.

Sample code:

```
name = input("What is your string? ")
your_check_function(name)
```

**Edit:** Now it works in python-3.x

Comment: There is no `raw_input` in python 3.x and he used the tag `python-3.x`. Please edit your answer and remove any abbreviation like "plz".

Comment: I just edited your answer, I hope you'll see what I meant :)